# Switching between Network Interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing

I am trying to write script to switch between two interfaces on a Linux machine, wlan0 and eth0.

My primary reference is:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/338100/forwarding-traffic-between-2-interfaces

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
```

My question is, after the above command, do the original packets still flow through eth0? If yes, how to stop them and only let them flow through wlan0?

And when I want to switch back to eth0 (and also forward wlan0 to eth0), what to do?

Finally, how to drop all the rules and return to normal?

Thanks.

Comment: That command doesn't "switch" anything. It tells the firewall to permit packets to flow from `eth0` to `wlan0` and on to some destination there. It does not permit packets to return along the same route, and it does not enable forwarding in and of itself.

Comment: Were you hoping to be able to switch your system to route its traffic out via either `eth0` or `wlan0`? LAN traffic or "everything"?

Comment: I was hoping to route everything to eth0 or wlan0. In the way similar to OS select eth0 over wlan0 even though both are active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to route out via different interfaces then ignore the firewall (the solution you found is for an entirely different requirement). Instead, look to the routing table.

The command `netstat -rn` will show you the interface that will accept a given destination. The command `route` can be used to modify the routing table, including defining the default gateway for traffic.

Here is an example of a routing table

```
netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth1
224.0.0.0       0.0.0.0         240.0.0.0       U         0 0          0 eth1
```

This shows that traffic for the LAN subnet 192.168.1.0/24 will use `eth0`, and 192.168.2.0/24 will use `eth1`. All other traffic will use the "default gateway" (destination 0.0.0.0), which is `eth1`. Your interfaces could easily be `eth0` and `wlan0`; it doesn't really matter.

To switch the default gateway from `eth1` to `eth0`, and presupposing that the local IP addresses for this system are 192.168.1.254 on `eth1` and 192.168.2.254 on `eth0`,

```
route delete default gw 192.168.2.254
route add default gw 192.168.1.254
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, how do I know 192.168.1.254 is GW for eth1 when it is not showing up in your netstat?

Comment: @LingyuanHe, the default route is that top row (starting with destination `0.0.0.0`). The outbound interface is `eth1` (right-hand column) and its local gateway is `192.168.2.254`. You have to know a gateway address from elsewhere - your ISP, your local Router, etc. and it must be reachable from your local network interface. Typically (but not exclusively) this means that the first three parts of the IP address will be the same.

Comment: I know it has been a while, but here is an interesting finding: I use a router to provide connection for both wlan0 and eth0, but different IP (192.168.1.115 and 130). Normally eth0 is the default one, then I do route delete gw 192.168.1.1 eth0 and route add gw 192.168.1.1 wlan0. Interestingly, although 115 is now the dominant IP, but I see incoming traffic captured in eth0 with 115 as IP, and outbound packet in wlan0 as expected, any clue?

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. That could make a good Question, though.